# Windows 7, there are two line in/line output on my desktop PC, one of them not working

Tags: windows, audio

Im using Windows 7. There are two input/output jack plug front (where the power button is) and back on the PC. The front plugins arent working (no sounds) while on the back works. I want the front to be working, what to do?

Comment: It would be helpful if you included the make/model of PC that you are using, if it is home built, include the motherboard, soundcard and case make/model

Answer (score 0):

Front audio connectors are typically

- headphone output
- microphone input

As you may know, you should not connect speakers, powered speakers or a normal amplifier to a headphone output because these expect different signal levels.

Read audio connectors are typically different signal levels and impedances from front connectors

- line out
- line in
- speakers out

  - left front
  - right front
  - etc

Sometimes they include

- microphone in

As you know, you must match devices to signal levels and impedances expected by each of these. For example, connecting a microphone to line-in will result in inaudible or very weak recording levels.

Comment: yes, they are headphone and microphone